# GCP - Can I use Compute Engine for Production MySQL DB

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is it alright to use Google Compute Engine virtual machines for MySQL DB?

db-n1-standard-2 costs around $97 DB for single Clould SQL instance and replication makes it double.

So I was wondering if its okay to use `n1-standard-2` which costs around $48 and the applications will be in Kubernetes cluster and the pods would connect to Compute Engine VM for DB connection. Would the pods be able to connect to Compute Engine VM?

Also is it true that Google doesn't charge `GKE Cluster Management Fees` when using Zonal Kubernetes cluster? When I check with calculator it shows they don't charge management fees.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely up to your needs. If you want to be on call for DB failover and replication management, it will definitely be cheaper to run it yourself. Zalando has a lot of Postgres-on-Kubernetes automation that is very good, but at the end of the day who do you want waking up at 2AM if something breaks. I will never run another production SQL database myself as long as I live, it's just always worth the money.